# How to load a classpath resource to an array of byte?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, embedded-resource

***I know*** how to get the inputstream for a given classpath resource, read from the inputstream until i reach the end, but it looks like a very common problem, and i wonder if there an API that I don't know, or a library that would make things as simple as

```
byte[] data = ResourceUtils.getResourceAsBytes("/assets/myAsset.bin")
```

or

```
byte[] data = StreamUtils.readStreamToEnd(myInputStream)
```

for example!

Comment: *"it looks like a very common problem"*  Commonly Java methods will accept an `InputStream`.

Comment: I _think_ that with Guava, this is more or less `Resources.toByteArray(Resources.getResource(contextClass, resourceName))`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson you just prevented me from doing something stupid in this precise case, thank you.

Comment: Entered as (alternate) answer.  ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have a look at Google guava `ByteStreams.toByteArray(INPUTSTREAM)`, this is might be what you want.

Answer (score 46):

Java 9 native implementation:

```java
    byte[] data = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("/assets/myAsset.bin").readAllBytes();
```

Comment: And which part appeared since Java 9 ?

Comment: method InputStream.readAllBytes() is since Java 9

Answer (score 25):

Although i agree with Andrew Thompson, here is a native implementation that works since Java 7 and uses the NIO-API:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/assets/myAsset.bin").toURI()));
```

Comment: If I'm running from a JAR, this fails with a FileSystemNotFoundException. I can get it to work by registering the JAR as a filesystem using FileSystems.newFileSystem, but I have to do that for each JAR I want to read resources from.

Comment: @JoeWhite Depending on the environment it may be required to remove the leading slash. E.g. in newer versions of Payara application server the class loader is able to find the resources only if it's a relative path.

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at Apache [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) - it has a bunch of methods to work with streams

Comment: more precisely something as `IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("XXX")`

Comment: This is useful for me in 2016. I am using the latest version of  IOUtils with Maven: [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5), through the suggestion of @yunandtidus Thanks.

Comment: My favourite is `IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("XXX", getClass().getClassLoader())` as it's a tiny bit shorter.

Answer (score 12):

I usually use the following two approaches to convert `Resource` into `byte[]` array.

### 1 - approach

What you need is to first call `getInputStream()` on `Resource` object, and then pass that to `convertStreamToByteArray` method like below....

```
InputStream stream = resource.getInputStream();
long size = resource.getFile().lenght();

byte[] byteArr = convertStreamToByteArray(stream, size);

public byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream stream, long size) throws IOException {

    // check to ensure that file size is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
    if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int line = 0;
    // read bytes from stream, and store them in buffer
    while ((line = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        // Writes bytes from byte array (buffer) into output stream.
        os.write(buffer, 0, line);
    }
    stream.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

### 2 - approach

As Konstantin V. Salikhov suggested, you could use `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` and call its `IOUtils.toByteArray(stream)` `static` method and pass to it `InputStream` object like this...

```
byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
```

`Note -` Just thought I'll mention this that under the hood  `toByteArray(...)` checks to ensure that file size is not larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so you don't have to check for this.

Comment: Good approach but I think that you means convertStreamToByteArray instead of Steam. :) Nice answer.

Comment: @PabloRS I've rectified the typo. Ta :)

Answer (score 4):

Commonly Java methods will accept an `InputStream`.   In that majority of cases, I would recommend passing the stream directly to the method of interest.

Many of those same methods will also accept an `URL` (e.g. obtained from `getResource(String)`).  That can sometimes be better, since a variety of the methods will require a repositionable `InputStream` and there are times that the stream returned from `getResourceAsStream(String)` will *not* be repositionable.