# Spring RestController returns wrong content type

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to return an image in a Spring RestController in the following way:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/images/{imageKey:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getImageAsResource(
        @PathVariable("imageKey") String imageKey) {
    Resource resource = resourceService.getImage(imageKey);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
}
```

The `resourceService` returns the image as a Java Resource object. Spring however sets the `Content-Type:` to `application/json` instead of the correct `image/...` type depending on the resource in the generated HTTP response.
How can I make Spring infer the correct content type from the returned resource?
The returned image resource may be a PNG, a JPG or a GIF.

Comment: does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file

Comment: the best thing is to convert your resource into a byte array https://stackoverflow.com/a/27969156/4423647. I guess you can obtain the input stream from the resource class if you are using spring resource interface

Comment: Set in explicitly like 'produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/images/{imageKey:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getImageAsResource(
            @PathVariable("imageKey") String imageKey) {
        Resource resource = resourceService.getImage(imageKey);
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        //Change it based on the type of image your are loading
        headers.put("Content-type", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: One thing about Spring is for sure. It *never* does the right thing out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `content type` produced by the method in the mapping. Use `@ResponseBody`annotation if you don't need control over HTTP headers & response codes.

```
 @ResponseBody
 @GetMapping(path = "/images/{imageKey:.+}", produces = MediaType. IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
 public Resource getImageAsResource(
                         @PathVariable("imageKey") String imageKey) {
    return resourceService.getImage(imageKey);
 }
```