# Spring Webserver not loading/transmitting images completely

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Java Spring program that is supposed to display a website with an image. When I run this in the development environment, it works without problems. When I compile my program to a jar file and run it, the image on the website is only partially loaded, the bottom half is just a blue/grey block. But this speaks for the fact that the image is found in the jar file after all.
I have already tried to send the image as byte array as well as base64 string, but both lead to the same behavior.
What can be the reason that it behaves so differently from development environment to compilation?

Here the code how i try to read the image.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
            Model model) throws IOException {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("base64Image", getBase64Image());
        return "greeting";
    }

    private String getBase64Image() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream imageStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bild.jpg");) {
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageStream.available()];
            imageStream.read(imageBytes);
            
            String encodeToString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
            System.out.println("Base64String length: "  + encodeToString.length());
            return encodeToString;
        }
    }

}
```

I have also already compared the lengths of the Base64 string for both variants. These are the same in the development environment as well as in the compiled program. Thus the complete image can be converted into a Base64 string also in the Jar version.

Comment: Is this a REST-Controller?

Comment: No it is just a "Controller", I've just edited my question so you can see the full class.

Comment: A good approach might be to craft a separate controller method just for the image. This can also boost browser caching. Essentially, you'd return the raw bytes from this method. For instance, you could use something like `@GetMapping(produces = ["image/png"])`. Give it a shot and see how it works for you!

Comment: I now noticed you're loading the image from your resources. Spring allows you to serve static files directly. So, in your template, you can simply use `<img src="/static/image/bild.jpg" />` to showcase your image. Makes things a bit smoother!

Comment: Aah okay, then I definitely gives this a try. Thank you very much. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, static loading of images only results in HTTP 404 messages for me. 

If I try the variant of providing the images via a separate controller, I run into the same problem as with all other methods. The image is loaded only to a small part. 
However always only with the variant, if I start the program over the Jar file. About the development environment (Eclipse) it works.

Comment: Have you configured spring correctly to serve static files?

Comment: Yes I think so :'D According to google the default setting is that everything in the static folder is statically available and actually I have not changed any settings. 
But I have also followed some tips from google to configure it manually. But all without success.

Comment: have you tried this (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) (Custom Directories).

Comment: What is the location of the file? Are you using Spring Boot? This question needs more information.

Comment: If you put the image in `src/main/resources/static/image/bild.jpg`, then the URL you need to use is `<img th:src="@{/image/bild.jpg}">`. So `static` should not be part of the URL.

Comment: The actual problem here is that you are not reading the full stream of bytes. The `available()` method might return less bytes compared to the full image, just what is available now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812559/how-to-load-a-classpath-resource-to-an-array-of-byte for a more robust method of converting the resource to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you @WimDeblauwe ,your html tag was the solution to display static images. I've used a normal html tag before and not the thymeleaf version..